# Pointer null after trying to set it to a valid iterator

Tags: c++, qt5

I am currently working with the Qt5 framework and I want to iterate over a list of QGraphicsItems to manipulate them conditionally. While I have already found a better way to solve my actual problem, it seems like this first approach has a problem which does not seem to make sense to me.

My situation is as follows. I have a method which serves as a getter for my List of QGraphicsItems. Its return value is QList. I am using that getter to retrieve my list and then I use the begin() method to retrieve an iterator of type QList::iterator. This I want to use to iterate over all the elements in the list, obviously.

So my code looks as follows:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *>::iterator it = this->items().begin();
std::cout << *(this->items().begin()) << std::endl;
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

Where this->items() returns our QList.

I would expect both of those console outputs to be the same. Though here is an example of actual output:

```
0x559716414740
0
```

This does not seem to make sense to me. As far as I am concerned, assigning the value of this->items().begin() to my it variable should not result in the it variable having any other value than what I get when I directly print this->items().begin().

I had been using a variable called auto it before, but just to make sure, I manually typed the type that the returned object should have. They both have identical behavior.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could point out my mistake here, as I sincerely am at a total loss. It seems like I can't have done anything wrong, but obviously it isn't working.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: please post a [mre], does `this->items()` return a copy of a `QList`?

Comment: It returns an object of type QList<QGraphicsItem *>. I would hope that it isn't just a copy, as I want to actually modify the list. But regardless of whether or not it is a copy, should it not still cause it to not be a nullpointer?

Comment: @VladisBecker There are no null pointers here. The zero comes from dereferencing an invalid iterator - which has undefined behaviour - and is just an arbitrary value.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for the clarification! This seems like an important distinction that I was very much not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `this->items()` returns an object, it is a temporary copy of your list. As you don't store this copy anywhere any iterators saved from it become invalid when the temporary list is destroyed at the end of the statement.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *>::iterator it;
{
   // create a temporary copy of items
   QList<QGraphicsItem *> items = this->items();
   it = items.begin();
}
// temporary "items" is destroyed, "it" is now pointing to a non-existent list and is inavlid
std::cout << *(this->items().begin()) << std::endl;
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
```

The solution is probably to make `items()` return the list by (possibly `const`) reference or as you're inside your own class calling `items()` is probably unnecessary, just access the member variable containing the list directly.

Comment: This is the correct answer and perfectly showed what the element about iterators is, that I was not understanding correctly. Great help!